# Compatibility for Non-CRAN Source Packages

Tags: r, package, cran

I wrote an internal R package and have saved it as a zipped source package. If a user has the most up-to-date version `R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)` that the package was built on, it runs fine. But if they have not updated yet, it does not install:

```
> list.files(pattern="tar")
[1] "rgridclus_0.2.0.tar.gz"
> install.packages("rgridclus", type="source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/plafortune/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘rgridclus’ is not available (for R version 3.2.4 Revised)
```

CRAN packages have a backwards compatibility process that allows newer package versions to be installed and used on old R versions with a warning:

```
> library(psych)
Warning message:
package ‘psych’ was built under R version 3.2.5
```

I will encourage the users to keep up with the newest R installs, but can I add this functionality in a non-cran package?

Comment: You never get the warning if you install from source.  Your `install.packages()` call above seems incorrect.

Comment: I thought the issue was in the source not the call. Thanks, I'll adjust the parameters to see if there's a default that needs changing

Comment: Found it. `repos=NULL` worked